# Linear Algebra: An explanation on a simplification

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Could someone please explain to me what property was used in simplifying this, or how this was achieved?

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Expand the determinant by the last row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This property:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeterminantExpansionbyMinors.html

Comment: hehe I love this place. Thanks.

Comment: Aka as [Laplace or cofactor expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion).